# change video chat frame rate tokbox

Tags: android, ios, video, opentok, tokbox

I am working on cross platform video conference App (iOS & Android) as a first phase, but I have problem that the video is disconnected when the network is week or slow, I found that the video it self frame rate is high, Is there any possible solution to change the frame rate of the video streams in the tokbox client SDKs (iOS or Android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use for iOS

use custom video Capturer
TBVideoCapture.h
TBVideoCapture.h

TBVideoRender.h
TBVideoRender.m

TBSubscriber.h
TBSubscriber.m

TBPublisher.h
TBPublisher.m

you can request them from Tokbox
then set this flag when you after initialize publisher

```
[_publisher.myVideoCapture setActiveFrameRate:5];
```

and for android

use CustomVideoCapturer.java from tokbox

and call

```
configureCaptureSize(75, 100, 30, 40, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can play around with the sample code in [Android or iOS](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/). In the sample code, there are examples where you can control everything down to the media content you want to stream (pictures are custom mp4 videos). You should be able to adjust the framerate and resolution as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/android/

Setting the resolution and frame rate for a video

You can set the frame rate for a publisher's stream by calling the Publisher(context, name, resolution, frameRate) constructor:

mPublisher = new Publisher(context,
  "Bob's video",
  Publisher.CameraCaptureResolution.HIGH,
  Publisher.CameraCaptureFrameRate.FPS_30);